# Where does the C++98 standard specify when a call to a static member is dependent within a template?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++98

Compiling with Clang 3.0 -std=c++98, the following code is accepted:

```
template<int>
struct I
{
    typedef int Type;
};

template<class>
struct S
{
    static int f(int);
    //static int f(int*);

    // implicitly instantiates I<sizeof(int)>
    typedef I<sizeof(f(0))>::Type Type; 
};

S<int>::Type s;
```

Uncommenting the overload of 'f' causes Clang to report an error "missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name". G++ 4.8 reports the same error with or without the overload. msvc10 does not give any errors with or without the overload.

Where does the standard say whether or not 'f' is dependent and 'typename' is required? If 'typename' is not required, where does the standard say whether or not overload resolution should be performed in this scenario?

EDIT:

To clarify: the reason I mention overload resolution is that it may be necessary to perform overload resolution to determine the value of the constant-expression 'sizeof(f(0))'. If (as I assume) overload resolution is not performed when determining whether an expression is type-dependent, the value of the constant-expression 'sizeof(f(0))' is impossible to determine (at parse time) when a dependent overload of 'f' exists: e.g.

```
template<int>
struct I
{
    typedef int Type;
};

template<class T>
struct S
{
    static T f(int);

    typedef typename I<sizeof(f(0))>::Type Type; 
};

S<int>::Type t;
```

Compiling with Clang 3.0 -std=c++98, this produces no errors. This seems correct to me, because the standard deems an expression to be type-dependent if it is an id-expression naming an object declared with a dependent type.

Comment: I fail to see dependent situation with or without the overload, so would bet on overlook in Clang. MSVC traditionally accepted code with missing typename so not necessarily conclusive though. Too bad we can no longer use Cameau online.

Comment: In C++2003, [temp.dep.expr]/4 "Expressions of the following forms are never type-dependent [...] `sizeof` *unary-expression*"; [temp.dep.constexpr]/2 "Expressions of the following form are value-dependent if the *unary-expression* is *type-dependent* or the
*type-id* is dependent [...] `sizeof` *unary-expression*"

Comment: I just saw that and added it to my comment :) Nevertheless, `f(0)` is not a type-dependent nor a value-dependent expression AFAIK

Comment: Interestingly, g++4.8 has the same problem with `typedef I<sizeof(&f)>::Type Type;` **iff** `f` is a static function (but not if it's a static data member).

Comment: Which version of clang do you use? My clang++3.2 compiles this w/o complaints.

Comment: The only rationale I can think of for considering 'f' to be type-dependent is that otherwise things start getting complicated when you add an overload of 'f' that is type-dependent - the rules for overload resolution in that scenario are not well defined.

Comment: IIRC overload resolution has nothing to do with whether a function call expression is dependent or not. Name lookup however is altered; that's another reason why I'd say that a function call expression *id-expression* `(` *expression-list* [opt] `)` is dependent IFF something in the *expression-list* is dependent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paragraph of the C++98 standard that covers this scenario is found in [temp.dep.expr]

> An id-expression is type-dependent if it contains:
>
> - an identifier that was declared with a dependent type,

This wording is somewhat vague about identifiers that are overloaded and potentially declared with more than one type, as reported in DR 541 : http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html

This was resolved (in a more recent draft) by changing the paragraph to read:

> An id-expression is type-dependent if it contains:
>
> - an identifier **associated by name lookup with one or more declarations** declared with a  dependent type,

When considering the following code:

```
template<class T>
struct S
{
    static int f(int);
    static int f(int*);

    static T g(int*);
    static int g(int);

    static const int x = sizeof(f(0));
    static const int y = sizeof(g(0));
};
```

My interpretation is that the identifier `f` in the expression `f(0)` is not dependent, while the identifier `g` in the expression `g(0)` is dependent.

When determining if a function-call expression is dependent - though overload resolution is not performed - all overloads of the function are considered.

Comment: It's voted into WP in 2010, pretty far form C++98. And I honestly don;t see what it changes for the case, in function f I see no dependent type directly or by association. Please elaborate the effect.

Comment: Elaborated! I'm in agreement that the expression within `sizeof()` should not be considered dependent unless it contains an identifier that was declared with a dependent type.

Comment: "My interpretation is that the identifier f in the expression f(0) is not dependent" It certainly is not a dependent name, [temp.dep]/1 clearly says so (`f` is not a *template-id*). Name lookup therefore is done using the default rules, which will find both overloads. +1

Answer (score 2):

Dependent names are defined in 14.6.2. gcc complains about `I<sizeof(f(0))>` being dependent, let's figure that.
14.6.2.1 last bullet:

> a template-id in which either the template name is a template parameter
>   or any of the template arguments is a dependent type or an expression
>   that is type-dependent or value-dependent

so `sizeof(f(0))` must be value-dependent. 14.6.2.3p2:

> Expressions of the following form are value-dependent if the unary-expression
>   is type-dependent ...
>   sizeof unary-expression

so we're dependent if f(0) considered dependent. (Little experimenting shows gcc treats member any function dependent and free functions not dependent.) 14.6.2.2:

> Except as described below, an expression is type-dependent if any subexpression is type-dependent.

And I don't see either type dependent subexpressions or anything relevant in the exception list.

Comment: That all agrees with my reading of the standard. So you're saying that a conformant implementation should not consider 'f' to be dependent in this scenario?

Comment: that's my conclusion, though unless someone closer to the standard weighs in I plan to ask it for confirmation. Sometimes text appearing elsewhere overrides the chain of evaluation

Answer (score 0):

`f` is a member of `S`, which is a template, so any use of `f` within `S` is dependent on the template parameters of `S`.

14.6.2.3 [temp.dep.constexpr] paragraph 2:

> An id-expression is value-dependent if:
>
> ...
>
> — it names a static member function that is a dependent member of the current instantiation

This applies to 'f' here, which is a dependent member of the current instantiation. 14.6.2.1 [temp.dep.types] paragraph 4:

> ...
>
> A name is a dependent member of the current instantiation if it is a member of the current instantiation that, when looked up, refers to at least one member of a class that is the current instantiation.

Consequently `sizeof(f(0))` is dependent, `I<sizeof(f(0))>` is dependent, and `I<sizeof(f(0))>::Type` needs `typename` to identify it as a type and not a data member.

gcc is therefore right to complain.

MSVC does late lookup with templates, so doesn't complain. This is a bug, but I don't think they ever intend to fix it.

Clang appears to have a bug here.

Comment: [temp.res] "Three kinds of names can be used within a template definition: 1. The name of the template itself, and names declared within the template itself, 2. Names dependent on a template-parameter, 3. Names from scopes which are visible within the template-definition." This says that within a template definition, the "name of the template itself" is not dependent. By this logic, neither `S` or `S<T>` are dependent.

Comment: [temp.de]/1 clearly says that `f` is **not** a dependent name.

Comment: I disagree: I've found the standard references to say that `f` **is** dependent, and edited my answer above.

Comment: I tried some googling, the first 3 hits https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/topic/com.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc/language/ref/name_binding.htm http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/02/06/dependent-name-lookup-for-c-templates/ http://womble.decadent.org.uk/c++/template-faq.html#non-dependent imply that names declared in the template itself are not dependent. Like f here. From the intent it does not sound logical either to bind them all late.

Comment: I tried to locate the quoted text "it names a static ..." in [temp.dep.constexpr] and can't see it in either C++03 or N3337 (the '98 is not at hand but IIRC it was same as +03), which document are you quoting?

Comment: You're quoting a proposed amendment that is part of DR 1471: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html. It looks like the rules changed significantly in C++0x.

Comment: Ok, I'll have to elaborate. In an expression of the form, `f(` *expression-list* `)`, the *unqualified-id* `f` does **not** denote a dependent name [temp.dep]/1. Therefore, `f(0)` is not per se a dependent expression. Because of [temp.dep.expr]/4 and [temp.dep.constexpr]/2, the expression `f(0)` had to be value-dependent to require the use of `typename` in the OP. [temp.dep.constexpr] describes what a value-dependent expression is, but IMO none of the conditions are fulfilled here.

Comment: @DyP: I arrived at the same conclusion even using the C++14 text (found the quote in N3690). Right the starting statement is incorrect, by using 14.6.2 f turns out NOT be dependent name by matching the filter and not matching any of the three bullets. Just being a member is not enough, it would be dependent with richer return type or arglist, not just by sitting there.